# CSS: can't get rid of the <li> bullet

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have defined a CSS for my basic document layout:

```
div#content li {
    font-size:95%;
    list-style-image:url(/css/bullet_list.gif);
    line-height:1.5;
}
```

deeper down in one document, I'm including a CSS file defining

```
.codexworld_rating_widget li{
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    float: left;
}
```

but the list element still displays the bullet graphic (`bullet_list.gif`) as if it would override the `list-style-image: none;` definition. Does anyone know why?

URL of the HTML document in question: http://www.psychotherapiepraxis.at/artikel/trauma/traumatherapie.phtml , the code in question is at the "Bewertung" section close to the end - the rating stars are covered by the bullets.

Comment: Use !important and problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting near enough the same elements as the original definition but include the selector.

```
div#content .codexworld_rating_widget li{
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    float: left;
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should apply list-style rules to UL(OL) tags and so far you are targeting LI(list item) tags

Comment: Incorrect, you can specify individual `li` tags to not have list styling. Would also recommend adding in example working code so the OP can fix his problem.

Answer (score 3):

CSS specificity gives `div#content li` a value of 102 while `.codexworld_rating_widget li` gets a value of 11. You need to either add a parent with an ID to `.codexworld_rating_widget li` or remove the id from `div#content li`. This [specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) can be very handy.

Comment: sounds more complicated to me than the answer I accepted and which helped right away, but looks like a fantastic tool which I'll sure bookmark in case I have any trouble again, thanks!

Comment: @richey: Don't delay having a look at the tool (or) reading up on specificity. Having an understanding of it would help you a lot while writing CSS.

Comment: Well, if you got some knowledge out of my answer as to how CSS specificity works, that's all that matter. ;)